# Several identical java scripts on one page

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, echarts, queryselector

I have a script from the echarts library, with which I build charts on my html page. I'm trying to call it several times for different tabs of my tabbable regions (**nav-tabs**).
I include the echarts library itself at the end of the body block

```
<script src="{% static 'js/echarts.min.js' %}"></script>
```

The code of the script executed several times on the page is as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
echarts.init(document.querySelector("#trafficChart1")).setOption({
tooltip: {
    //tooltip settings
},
legend: {
    //legend settings
},
series:[{
    //diagramm settings
data: [
   {value: 50,  name: 'Region_100'},
   {value: 150, name: 'Region_200'},
   {value: 250, name: 'Region_300'}
      ]
}]
});
});
```

For each of the tabs I tried using a **different selector**:

```
<div id="trafficChart1" style="min-height: 300px;" class="echart"></div>   
<script> 
    //here is the code of the above script
</script>
```

Accordingly, for the other two tabs the code will be the same, but the selectors (**#trafficChart2**, **#trafficChart3**) and data for the charts will change.

In the end, it all looks something like this (the first tab of the nav-tabs block)

[the first tab of the nav-tabs block 2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSjEs.jpg)

But in the 2022 and 2023 tabs the charts are not displayed, although they are marked with identifiers ('**trafficChart2**' and '**trafficChart3**' respectively).

[2022 and 2023 tabs where charts are not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XySMq.jpg)

Help me understand how to implement the construction of diagrams in different tabs of a nav-tabs block, that is, in essence, ***call the javascript several times on one page***.